# Having multiple time the same object in a core data one-to-many relationship

Tags: core-data, nsarray, magicalrecord, nsset

I have two entities in my Core Data model: Library and Book. They are linked by a To Many relationship between Library and Book.
However, in my example I have the exact same book twice in my library and when I try to add them to my Library, only one appears. I search a bit and noticed that in the Library object, books are stored as a `NSSet`.
Does anyone know how I could store the books in a `NSArray` instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (well, unless you do away with the `Book` entity and use a transformable attribute but that isn't a good solution).

The obvious choice would be to add a `count` attribute onto your `Book` entity so that you can record how many of that book you have. What impact this might have on the rest of your design is something you need to consider.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution I was thinking of, but I was hoping there was a better solution. Could you explain what is a transformable attribute?

Comment: In the info inspector (where you set the type to string / integer / etc) you can choose transformable. Results in binary data storage. So you can't use it in any predicate. Not a good option...

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode sidebar, there is a checkbox named "Ordered relationship", but as Wain mentioned, this won't solve the duplicate issue. But, it will make it save the books in an ordered collection (`NSOrderedSet`).

I would make a new entity, `LibraryBook`, that had a to-one relationship with `Book`, and to-one to `Library`. You could than have two `LibraryBook`s in one `Library`, both pointing at the same `Book`.

Comment: You still can't have duplicates in an ordered set

Comment: Well, whether that's actually part of question is debatable, order isn't explicitly asked for, duplicates are

Comment: Sorry, misinterpreted the question. Updated it!

Comment: Yes, I'm actually asking about duplicates and not about the order. Sorry my question wasn't clear.

Comment: `NSOrderedSet` is not like `NSArray`, it has order, but it's still a set and sets can't contain duplicates. The entity based solution is good (though perhaps a little heavy depending on how frequently duplicates will exist).